# Why are there no direct (non-stop) flights from Sydney in Australia to Arica in Chile?

Tags: air-travel, australia, chile

I want to book a direct flight over the Pacific but I found none. I wonder where can I find any ticket that meets this criteria. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Arica, Chile only has a population of about 222,000 people, so it would be very unlikely to have any long distance, direct, non-stop flights to anywhere.

Edit: There are direct, non-stop flights between Santiago, Chile, and Sydney, Australia, but they may not operate daily, or year round. On some days you would need to do an enroute stop in Auckland, New Zealand.

Comment: thank you for answering!, sorry this might be a second question, i wonder if  it's possible to book a flight that goes from sydney to chile and stop in auckland ?

Comment: Actually QF27/28 is a direct service SYD-SCL

Comment: @hamza yes LATAM fly from Sydney to Auckland and onwards to Santiago. Just go on their website to book it (but you can also fly Qantas directly between Santiago and Sydney)

Comment: La Paz may be a better alternative (nearest large international airport). And it is one airport to visit: airport on flat 4000m plateau (there will depressurization at landing).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi La Paz does not have service to Australia, so flying via Santiago with a domestic connection/separate flight to Arica is almost certainly cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Arica has a tiny domestic airport that only serves 3 different destinations.

[image]

> i wonder if it's possible to book a flight that goes from sydney to chile and stop in auckland ?

Yes. Here are options for Sydney->Auckland->Santiago for Oct 18

[image]

You can get tickets from Sydney to Arica, but none stop in Auckland and most include an airport change in Melbourne (not a good idea). I think you are better off booking from Sydney to Santiago (you have to go through there anyway) and a separate ticket from Santiago to Arica.